# Datatables: Change height of table not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I am using a Jquery Datatables table with bPaginate = false and sScrollY is some fixed height. Ultimately I want the table to resize on the window.resize event.

To get this to work I have built a smaller testcase: In the following code snippets I want the table to resize when I click the button

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link class="jsbin" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.13/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input id="button" type="button" value="Click me!" />
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Rendering engine</th>

            <th>Browser</th>
            <th>Platform(s)</th>
            <th>Engine version</th>
            <th>CSS grade</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="odd gradeX">
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td>Internet
                 Explorer 4.0</td>
            <td>Win 95+</td>
            <td class="center"> 4</td>
            <td class="center">X</td>

        </tr>
        <tr class="even gradeC">
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td>Internet
                 Explorer 5.0</td>
            <td>Win 95+</td>
            <td class="center">5</td>
            <td class="center">C</td>

        </tr>
        <tr class="odd gradeA">
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td>Internet
                 Explorer 5.5</td>
            <td>Win 95+</td>
            <td class="center">5.5</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>

        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Rendering engine</th>
            <th>Browser</th>
            <th>Platform(s)</th>

            <th>Engine version</th>
            <th>CSS grade</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#button').click(function() {
  console.log('Handler for .click() called.');
  table = $('#example').dataTable();
  settings = table.fnSettings();  
  console.log('old:' + settings.oScroll.sY);
  settings.oScroll.sY = '150px';
  console.log('new:' + settings.oScroll.sY);
  table.fnDraw(false);
});
$('#example').dataTable({
  "sScrollY": "350px",
  "bPaginate": false,
  "bJQueryUI": true
});
```

Console output is as expected:

```
Handler for .click() called.
old:350px
new:150px
```

but the table doesn't update! Any idea what I am doing wrong?

A live example can be found here: http://jsbin.com/anegiw/12/edit

Comment: That would reinitialize the table, so it might work for this particurlar snippet. But would it be appropriate for a window.resize event handler, which is called many times during a resize of the broser window?

Comment: Actually, i've just tried it in the window.resize event: it works but is terribly slow, even on a modern machine

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Ok what seems to work nicely is to do tap into the elements added by the datatbables framework:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  console.log($(window).height());
  $('.dataTables_scrollBody').css('height', ($(window).height() - 200));
});

$('#example').dataTable({
  "sScrollY": ($(window).height() - 200),
  "bPaginate": false,
  "bJQueryUI": true
});
```

This example lets the table resize smoothly with the window.

Live example: http://jsbin.com/anegiw/18/edit

Answer (score 0):

It might be the case that the sScrollY value only sets the size of the table on initialize and then when you change the value it does not reside the table. That value might only be used to tell datatables "after this amount of scrolling render more results" so you might have to create a facade that updates the sScrollY and then manually updates the css width of that table to the desired height.

Comment: It would explain a lot, but there are others questions, where the answer is that it *should* work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7634066/how-to-dynamically-change-jquery-data-tables-height

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me:

```
#data_wrapper.dataTables_wrapper
{
     height: 700px !important;
     background-color: #F1F1F1 !important;
}
#data_wrapper .fg-toolbar.ui-toolbar.ui-widget-header.ui-helper-clearfix.ui-corner-bl.ui-corner-br
{
       position: absolute;
       width: 100%;
       bottom: 0;
}
```

You can change the height as per your number of records.