# jquery - datatable change sScrollY

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I would like to change size of scrollable area of a datatable.

```
$('#example').dataTable({"sScrollY": 100});
//some stuff..
$('#example').dataTable({"sScrollY":101}); //wrong: cannot reinitialize
```

Comment: I found a solution / workaround.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7678345/datatables-change-height-of-table-not-working

Comment: Wait you are attempting to resize the datatable after a page resize? That isn't what you asked in your code above can you confirm that is what you are trying to do.

Comment: I am trying to resize the scrollable area of a datatable, not the datatable itself (btw: I found the answer).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$('.dataTables_scrollBody').css('height', 400);
```

Comment: This changes the height of the table not of the scrollable area

Comment: This method changes size of scrollable area of datatable. It of course has a side effect too - it changes size of the whole table itself - but the given value will be the height of the scrollable area and the height of the whole table.

Comment: you should use 400px instead of just 400

Answer (score 4):

To change the Y Scroll use the below code,

```
var objDataTable = $('#example').dataTable({"sScrollY" : 100});
objDataTable.fnSettings().oScroll.sY = 101;
objDataTable.fnDraw();
```

Answer (score 3):

If yoy have several datatables you can access each by the wrapper:

```
$('#example').dataTable({'sScrollY': 100});
//some stuff..
objDataTable.fnSettings().oScroll.sY = '225px';
$('#example_wrapper').children('.dataTables_scroll').children('.dataTables_scrollBody').css('height', '225px');
```

Answer (score 1):

For jquery.dataTables 1.10.x :

```
$('div.dataTables_scrollBody').height( 400 );
```

This is the recommended way according to Datatables documentation. According to the same documentation the use of the settings object is discouraged as it is internal.

Comment: In my case, this didn't work. nagy.zsolt.hun's solution did.

Answer (score 0):

I had to combine both to solve my problem. In my case I want to do endless pagination, the problem is that after window resize, the height of dataTables_scrollBody stay fixed, so I have to adjust the oScroll to show the table data with scrolling bar. Setting the dataTables_scrollBody height will work when window size change, but after table redraw it will roll back using the old sScrollY value, and Neo's code fixed this. :)

```
objDataTable.fnSettings().oScroll.sY = 101;
objDataTable.fnDraw();
$('.dataTables_scrollBody').css('height', 400);
```

Comment: you should use 400px instead of just 400