# Change settings in modern jQuery DataTables after initialization

Tags: jquery-plugins, datatables

I'm using new version of DataTables ( [www.datatables.net](http://www.datatables.net/), not a [legacy.datatables.net](http://legacy.datatables.net/) ). I have initial `scrollY` value, and want to change it on some events.

I tried all approaches I can imagine, but none of them worked (please check out [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fLcasju4/17/)):

```
var dt = $('#example').DataTable({
        scrollY: "200px",
    });

$('#resize').click(function() {
    // Doesn't affect anything
    dt.settings({
        scrollY: "100px",
    });

    // TypeError: Cannot read property 'sY' of undefined
    dt.settings().oScroll.sY = "100px";

    // TypeError: undefined is not a function
    // http://datatables.net/reference/api/ doesn't work as described :(
    dt.Api();

    // To redraw table after
    dt.draw();
});
```

There are **two very confusing things**:

First: Api object can't be created, as it described in [documentation](http://datatables.net/reference/api/):

```
$('#example').DataTable().Api(); // undefined is not a function
```

Second: I can see needed field in designer, but can't access it by name (other fields in first request were cropped by me):

[image: confusing]

I don't know, how it is even possible.

Comment: Here is an example how it was done in legacy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14685865/jquery-datatable-change-sscrolly

Comment: I found workaround for this case: `$('.dataTables_scrollBody').css('height', 100);`, but that doesn't solve accessing datatable settings.